# method to search in stack using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, search, stack

I need to search for an element in a stack using recursion
I cannot use other data structures 
I cannot change the stack
this is what I did and it's wrong

```
public static<E> boolean se(LinkedStack<E>s,E a) {
    boolean answer=false;
    E tmp=s.pop();
    if(tmp==a)
        answer= true;
    else {
        se(s, a);
        s.push(tmp);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: `tmp==a` comparing objects like that is probably wrong

Comment: Where is `LinkedStack` coming from?  It is not part of the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (ie set answer to) the results of calling se recursively.

```
public static<E> boolean se(LinkedStack<E>s,E a) {
    boolean answer=false;
    E tmp=s.pop();
    if(tmp.equals(a))
        answer= true;
    else {
        answer = se(s, a);
        s.push(tmp);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: @RobOhRob I have corrected my answer as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this.  It uses the Java `Stack` but the process should be the same.

```
    public static <E> boolean se(Stack<E> s, E a) {
        boolean answer;
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            // stack isn't empty so get value
            E k = s.pop();

            // meets criteria?
            if (k.equals(a)) {
                // yes so put it back on.
                s.push(k);
                // an return true
                return true;
              // doesn't meet criteria
            } else {
                // call again
                answer = se(s, a);
                // when the result is returned, the
                // values in the call chain will be
                // returned to the stack in the order they
                // were removed.
                s.push(k);

                //And the answer from each previous call will be
                // returned, resulting in the final answer.
                return answer;
            }
        }
        // stack empty with no success
        // return false
        return false;

    }
```